# Adding data in an array asynchronasuly

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, nsoperationqueue

I have 8 separate function, and all of them returning a data I need to store the data in an array. What is the best way to store the data into the array and notify that array have stored all data. So that I can pass it in another view controller. for example i have f1(), f2()... and all return a string and I want to store it in a dataArray. if all function done there job I have to pass this data to another vc.

Comment: Does order matter? Does the first element of the final array have to be the result of `f1()`, or can it be whatever finishes first?

Comment: No,  order does not matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313084/pseudo-codes-for-semaphores-in-operating-systems Can someone from here help me answer this question? TQ ^^

Answer (score 2):

The tool you want is a dispatch group and a serial dispatch queue to gather the results. It's important that you serialize updating the results, because modifying an array is not thread-safe. You can wrap all of this up into a generic solution of course. As a quick example that hasn't been heavily tested (and is slightly weird because it is self-retaining, so maybe that's confusing), but demonstrates the basic approach:

```
class Dispatcher<Element> {
    let resultsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "dispatcher") // Default is serial
    var results: [Element] = []
    init(functions: [() -> Element], completion: @escaping ([Element]) -> Void) {

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
        for f in functions {
            queue.async(group: group) {
                let result = f()
                self.resultsQueue.sync { self.results.append(result) }
            }
        }

        // Just picking main here as a random place to perform the update.
        // You could also pass it in.
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { completion(self.results) }
    }
}

Dispatcher(functions: [{ return 1 }, { return 2 }], completion: { print($0) })
```

> I have to pass this data to another vc

Note that this strongly suggests you're doing something incorrect. View controllers should not compute data and should definitely not asynchronous pass data to other view controllers. View controllers are responsible for *displaying* data and are free to be destroyed any time they are off screen (and the second view controller may not be onscreen or even exist when the completion block runs). The work should be moved to model classes and the view controllers should observe the model and update themselves then the model finishes its work. But this Dispatcher class can still be helpful for that.

Comment: thanks @rob Napier. Please also review whatever I have done in answer section

Answer (score 0):

For notifications have to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotificationCenter)

In view controller viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
                                             name:@"DataReceivedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSArray *receivedData = notification.object;

    NSLog(@"%@",receivedData);
}
```

In function class

```
- (void)f1
{
    //Store the received data in array
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(nonnull id), ..., nil];

    //Post notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataReceivedNotification" object:data];
}
```

Comment: This does not meet my requirement

Answer (score 0):

For better reference you can see the link http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/